# setting up ELB using ruby api

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm new to ruby and AWS and trying to get around load balancing 
I know How to get a list of instances

```
ec2 = AWS::EC2.new.regions[AWS_CON['region']]
key_pair = ec2.key_pairs[AWS_CON['key_pair']]


instances = ec2.instances.create(
    :image_id => AWS_CON['image_id'],
    :instance_type => AWS_CON['instance_type'],
    :count => count,
    :security_groups => AWS_CON['security_groups'],
    :key_pair => key_pair)
```

and its working fine

now I want to attach them to a ELB and just cant figure it out from AWS API SDK
what I want on the same logic is :

```
elb = AWS::ELB.new(
:name => 'my-lb')
elb.create(
:instance_collection => EC2collection,
:security_group => SecGroup)
```

can you please lead me to the right direction ?